# remove flexmenu attribute from a td

Tags: jquery

```
<tbody id="last" data-bind="foreach: stuDetails.GetStudentSearchModel">
                        <tr>
                            <td data-bind="text: $index()+1"></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                            <td data-bind="text: studid"></td>
                            <td data-bind="trimText: studname"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

the below code will add flexmeny to all td

```
var TrLoop = 1;
               $("#tblStuList tbody tr").each(function () {
                   $(this).find('td').each(function () {
                       $(this).addflexmenu('flexmenu' +StudIDArray[TrLoop]);
                      // $(this).attr('nowrap', 'nowrap');
                   });
                   TrLoop = TrLoop + 1;
               });
```

How I can remove the flexmenu attribute from the check box td

```
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
```

in additional to that I want to add nowrap to:

```
<td data-bind="trimText: studname"></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all other `td` elements has `data-bind` attributes you can target only those `td` elements

```
$("#tblStuList tbody tr").each(function () {
    $(this).find('td[data-bind]').each(function () {
        $(this).addflexmenu('flexmenu' + StudIDArray[TrLoop]);
        // $(this).attr('nowrap', 'nowrap');
    });
    TrLoop = TrLoop + 1;
});
```

Another option is to target the `td` with its position - it is the second `td`

```
$("#tblStuList tbody tr").each(function () {
    $(this).find('td:not(:nth-child(2))').each(function () {
        $(this).addflexmenu('flexmenu' + StudIDArray[TrLoop]);
        // $(this).attr('nowrap', 'nowrap');
    });
    TrLoop = TrLoop + 1;
});
```

or you can say td without input

```
$("#tblStuList tbody tr").each(function () {
    $(this).find('td:not(:has(input))').each(function () {
        $(this).addflexmenu('flexmenu' + StudIDArray[TrLoop]);
        // $(this).attr('nowrap', 'nowrap');
    });
    TrLoop = TrLoop + 1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Arun it works, I also add nowrap to the fourth td using (:nth-child(4)) :)